# Oracle 11g : Sql Developer : How to execute more than one anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to execute a list of anonymous block in sql developer. But when ever execute a anonymous block example

```
Begin
 execute do something
end;
```

it works but if i execute more than one anonymous block such as

```
Begin
 execute do something
end;
Begin
 execute do something
end;
```

it throws

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use forward slash in between

```
Begin
 execute do something
end;
/

Begin
 execute do something
end;
/
```

Answer (score 4):

Execute all queries in a same begin end block or wrap all in a begin end block.

Like

```
Begin
 execute do something;
 execute do something;
End;
```

Or

```
Begin
Begin
 execute do something;
end;
Begin
 execute do something;
End;
End;
```